# Ignore tags inside div until clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jinja2

I have the following function, which expands word-wrapped text within a `tr` tag, if the tag is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.css('white-space') === 'nowrap') {
            $this.css('white-space', 'normal');
        }
        else {
            $this.css('white-space', 'nowrap');
        }
    });
});
```

I'm using this function as I want text within the tables cells to display only on one row (in essence hiding the inner `p` tag), until clicked on by a user. The problem, however, is that `nowrap` breaks lines for `br` and `p` tags, and I have several of these for formatting purposes. How can I turn on these tags, only when the `tr` is clicked?

html:

```
<td>
   <div>
       {{ post.person }}
          <p>
              Message:
              <br>
              {{ post.message }}
          </p>
   </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Make them `display: inline-block`. Instead of toggling CSS, add a class and toggle that

Comment: I've tried that approach, however for some reason my classes aren't applying. Do you know why that could be? It works fine when I directly set the `p` style to `display: none`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/a0cvtjdo/

Comment: remove `<br />`. instead do this: `<p><span>Message:</span><div>{{ post.message }}</div></p>` then solution of @YaakovAinspan will do the job.

Comment: @mrReiha, you can't put a `div` inside a `p`

Comment: @YaakovAinspan In a gorgeous world you're using `<br />` everything is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a maximum height (1.2em is the default line height relative to the font size) to your div and set `overflow: hidden`. Then you'll see only 1 line. Once clicked, toggle another class that set `overflow: visible` and `height: auto`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tr').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).find(".a").toggleClass("expand");
  });
});
```

```css
.a{
  height: 1.2em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.expand{
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="a">
        {{ post.person }}
        <p>
          Message:
          <br> {{ post.message }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For some reason, my classes still aren't applying. When I set `.a` to `display: none`, for example, nothing changes. Why do you think this could be?

Comment: Yep, I've got it working now, was missing a closing slash on my link to the css. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @LaurieBamber and Itay: Since messing with the height can create other rendering issues, instead do this: `.a p{
display: none;
}

.a.expand p{
display: block;
}`

Comment: Yes...and if there is no `div` with class `a` one can't click either ;) Still, since the OP _does_ have a text before the `p`, it is better to avoid tricks with the height.

Comment: {{ post.person }} can be long too. There are too many unknown factors so it's hard to give the optimal solution without all the factors. Height seems to work for the op